# What are the different counters to look for packet drops in a linux server?

Tags: linux, networking

Apart from the usual suspects that is :

ethtool -S 
tc -s -d qdisc
netstat

I don't see anything that is reflecting drops in any of these counters,but i see TCP re-transmits happening in a back-back connecting when i have 16 iperf connections between DUT and the peer

Any other places i can look at for finding out where drops are happening ?

Thanks
Som

Answer (score 0):

What kind of connection do you have between the peers? Is your network stack doing retransmits because some ACKs are delayed?

Comment: It's a back-back ,so no chance of network congestion et al... Err..how do i verify that?

Comment: This is the command that i am using

Comment: iperf -c <peer ip> -l60000 -i5 -t60000 -P16 -w2048k